# Android application : Consuming WCF inUnity

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to consume a WCF within Unity 2018.1.1f, Although  I have followed this [wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Webservices_In_Unity) , and this [article](https://stpdev.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/consuming-a-wcf-service-from-unity3d/) , When I execute the application in Unity editor, I can cousume my WCF without problem, but when I build the APK  I'm not able to cosume the WCF via my phone, i get the error :

> Error deserializing configuration section webServices:This element is not currently associated with any context

Bellow is my configuration :

[image]

Any help please.

Comment: Find something else to use other than WCF in Unity. Most that get WCF working in Unity usually run into issues on some platforms.

Comment: Like what? is WebService can do the job ?

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to accomplish so it's hard to comment on that. While believe that WCF is made for Windows only probably due to it's dependencies, I suggest you look at [this](http://gyanendushekhar.com/2016/04/21/how-to-call-wcf-service-in-unity/) post and make sure you're using the correct dll.